# Merge Replication with Geometry data type

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

The Merge Agent failed because the schema of the article at the Publisher does not match the schema of the article at the Subscriber. This can occur when there are pending DDL changes waiting to be applied at the Subscriber. Restart the Merge Agent to apply the DDL changes and synchronize the subscription.  (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147199398)
>

> Error converting data type varchar to geometry. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 8114)
>   Get help: http://help/8114

Comment: I can has context?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a bug but the only way that I can get geometry data to successfully replicate is to use the following settings on the publisher (Article Properties, set properties for All tables) -:

```
Convert filestream to MAX data types - True
```

Strangely, "Convert Spatial to MAX data types" doesn't fix the problem.  It's also necessary to select "Copy spatial indexes - True" for spatial index support.  Other than that, the defaults should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To produce above error, Follow the below steps:

--STEP 1 : Create a database on sql server 2008 r2 enterprise or developer edition
create database replicationtest;
go

IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.SpatialTable', 'U' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.SpatialTable;
GO

--STEP 2: create a table storing geometry data type
CREATE TABLE SpatialTable 
    ( id int IDENTITY (1,1),
    GeomCol1 geometry, 
    GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() );
GO

--STEP 3: insert some sample records
INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeomCol1)
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 0));

--STEP 4: --configure distributor on this enterprise edition
--Create a publication on above database

--STEP 5: Create a subscriber on SQL Server 2008 r2 express edition(using push subscription)

--STEP 6: Now once snapshot is applied then both databases are synchronized

--STEP 7: Insert a row into above table on publisher
INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeomCol1)
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0));
GO

--STEP 6: Launch replication monitor and observe the error:

The Merge Agent failed because the schema of the article at the Publisher does not match the schema of the article at the Subscriber. This can occur when there are pending DDL changes waiting to be applied at the Subscriber. Restart the Merge Agent to apply the DDL changes and synchronize the subscription. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147199398) >

```
Error converting data type varchar to geometry. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 8114) Get help: http://help/8114
```

Answer (score 0):

Set SQL Server 2008 compatibility settings to SQL Server 2008.

It might be set to SQL Server 2005 compatibility, which doesn't support Geometry column.